# How to get spa pump to quit leaking around new plug with o-ring

Tags: plumbing

I have an XP2 Spa pump that I can’t get the plug to seat and seal. The plastic plug is difficult to start. Once I get it started and turning, right about the time it starts to tighten, the plug acts like it is stripped, as it turns loosely and will not tighten. Tried two new plugs and same thing happens. I would hate to have to pull the pump (one of two and of course it is the one in the back).  Looks like the plate threads are also plastic. Any suggestions? Will Teflon tape work? I’m at a loss and at maximum frustration.

Comment: Could you post a few pictures of it?

Comment: Are these the drain plugs? You may be threading it in too far, so you end up going past the threads. I would use teflon tape on the threads as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I did us the tape and it didn’t work. So, I took the end cap off and the inside threads on the cap are stripped. I tried to thread the plug back in and it is not going in straight. Should I try to tap it? HeliCoil? Any suggestions?

Comment: There are products out there for hot tub repair, a plast-aid is one such product. I bought some to repair a hot tub, but got rid of the tub before using it. It is a moldable plastic 2-part type epoxy. Can be used for lots of stuff. But you might also look into just replacing the pump cover, or the pump. Not the motor, just the pump, also known as wet-end. Whats the model of the pump? Brand of the tub, model of the tub?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I ended up tapping out the threads and using a course threaded stainless steel hex head bolt. Worked like a charm - better than the plastic plug.